# Heroku cli (brew install heroku): ArgumentError: user emixam23 doesn't exist

Tags: macos, heroku, homebrew, heroku-cli

I am trying to install Heroku on my Mac following the doc https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install but I am getting an issue while running the command to install heroku:

```
MBP-de-Emixam23:~ emixam23$ brew install heroku
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing heroku from heroku/brew
==> Downloading https://cli-assets.heroku.com/homebrew/node-12.16.2.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/emixam23/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5787f9331a645901d1511ff2973c961e1037248779c2b5628ec2601273fb979b--node-12.16.2.tar.xz
==> Downloading https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-v7.42.4/heroku-v7.42.4.tar.
Already downloaded: /Users/emixam23/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/15cbf813f5f04cde9c65e953825e9514cfe5f571108d68a5284521d8592bcf4f--heroku-v7.42.4.tar.xz
==> Installing dependencies for heroku/brew/heroku: heroku/brew/heroku-node
==> Installing heroku/brew/heroku dependency: heroku/brew/heroku-node
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  ArgumentError: user emixam23 doesn't exist
```

Any idea? :o

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you run _brew doctor_ ?

Comment: I did a brew upgrade and everything went fine when trying again :/ no idea what append

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my case, the issue was caused by the environment variable USER.

To find out if env vars that could be causing the issue, execute:

```
printenv | grep $TEXT_IN_ERROR
```

where the variable is the following value:

```
  ArgumentError: user $TEXT_IN_ERROR doesn't exist
```

Comment: Same for me.. it was just the USER set in my bash_profile that was causing the issue

Comment: Same for me. It was an env variable in .zshrc

Comment: Thank you, forgot USER was a special variable in unixland and had set it for my own purposes.